# Finder stuck at starting

Tags: macos, finder, disk-utility

I have a big problem with my mac book pro 15" - maverick.
Yesterday I was using my mac normally and I shutdown it normally. Today, I turn on and everything is fine until when I have to insert my password. I insert it and then I can see the desktop and I can move the mouse but nothing works, I can't click anywhere and the dock doesn't appear. After a while the mouse convert itself in the "circular rainbow" (sorry but i've no idea about the name of that ). 
I tried to fix with the disk utility recovering the permission but nothing changed. 
Any idea of what happened?  
EDIT: I tried to create a new user and it don't stuck. So it's a problem of the user.

Comment: The "circular rainbow" is commonly known as a [pinwheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinning_pinwheel) or spinning pinwheel.

Comment: did you do another restart after that? Same result?  Do you have any other user account that you can log into on machine?

Comment: I've tried several times, but nothing changed. I have only my account :/

Comment: does it start in Safe mode ?

Comment: I-ve left it more or less 1 hour without touching and the the pinwheel disappear and looks like everything is fine now but I-ve still not restarted the mac yet, I-m scared :)

Comment: Your computer was STUCK doing something, if you want to find out what, open Console and scroll back to the time stamp of the event.

Comment: Can I ask you what should I search? I've never use the console so I don't know what to look for, and from the boot until when I can use my mac there are a lot of row, like more than 100!